# Is there anyway to make a loop in angularjs template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I'm developing an app with onsen UI (angularjs) + cordova.
So I have a page with comments and each comment has a button "like".
I must show a different button when the user already liked the page.
Then I created a CSS class named "active". 
But for I can use this class, I should create a loop inside angular expression, because I get returned from backend an javascript object with user interactions for each comment. Example:

The page has 3 comments: id 1, id 2 and id 3
The user liked comment number 1 and 3.
The object returned is:
[object][0] id => 1,
[object][1] id => 3

Then I show the comments with an angularjs loop, like this:

```
 ng-repeat="comment in comments | limitTo: 6"
```

Ok, now lets try to show the different button for already "liked" (with active css class) and normal button if user not "liked" yet.

```
<button class="button btnice {{ event.event_id in interactions ? 'active' : 'normal'}}">
```

So is it possible? If not, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's absolutely possible:

In your HTML:

```
<button class="button btnice" ng-class="isLiked(commentId) ? 'active' : 'normal'">
```

Then, add a `isLiked` function to your controller:

```
var likedComments = [{interaction_id: "2", value: "1", comment_id: 1}, {...}];

$scope.isLiked = function(commentId){
    return likedComments.some(function(interaction){
        return interaction.comment_id === commentId;
    });
};
```

This should do the trick. This returns `true` if the `likedComments` array of objects contains one or more objects with `comment_id === commentId`.

Comment: Objects are more troublesome to iterate over to find a comment on. If that object _only_ contains a list of comment ids, you're better off using an array. How would you structure the object?

Comment: Because there are other interaction types. But all I need to check is the commend_id, because other interactions has comment_id = null

Comment: `ng-class="isLiked(commentId) ? 'active' : 'normal'"` <-- you need to use the correct variable for the `commentId` there.

Comment: @harleydavi: did it work for you after changing the ID? I also improved the code in the answer a bit.

Comment: Hey Cerbrus, Thank you for your attention. Unfortunately It did not worked yet. I did not unterstood your variable "interaction". I am using $scope.interaction and tried to change it too, but had no success. The commentID in HTML is right.

Comment: Strange. I tried to change the commentID inside js function to static and it worked, but in HTML I did inspect and the variable is passing right id. When I inspect HTML it shows right, look: ng-class="isLiked(21) ? 'active' : 'normal'". So it doesn't works. But if I change commentID variable to static '21' inside js function, it works.

Comment: I did `console.log(commentId);` and it prints twice each ID. Is this the problem?

Comment: Thank you bro, I've changed the "===" to "==" and it worked perfectly. Thanks so much